# como seleccionar lo que tengo en un textView para que me aparezcan dos botones

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]lo que hago es lo siguiente: en un textView muestro información de una base de datos sql server, pero ahora lo que estoy intentando hacer es al momento de seleccionar un de las filas que aparecen en el textView me muestre dos botones alguna ayuda o consejo que me puedan dar este es el codigo:

```
while (rs.next()){
                Tipo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tipo);
                Sucursal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tipo);
                Cliente = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tipo);
                Monto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tipo);

//Obtiene texto actual en TextView.
                String textoTipo = Tipo.getText().toString();
                //Al texto actual agrega el texto que se encuentra en el cursor.
                Tipo.setText(textoTipo += rs.getString(1 )+ " - MONTO $");

//Obtiene texto actual en TextView.
                String textoMonto = Tipo.getText().toString();
                //Al texto actual agrega el texto que se encuentra en el cursor.
                Tipo.setText(textoMonto += rs.getString(6)+ "\n" +"SOLICITA: ");

//Obtiene texto actual en TextView.
                String textoSucursal = Sucursal.getText().toString();
                //Al texto actual agrega el texto que se encuentra en el cursor.
                Sucursal.setText(textoSucursal += rs.getString(3 )+ "\n" +"CLIENTES: ");

//Obtiene texto actual en TextView.
                String textoCliente = Cliente.getText().toString();
                //Al texto actual agrega el texto que se encuentra en el cursor.
                Cliente.setText(textoCliente += rs.getString(4 )+ "\n_____________________________________________________"+ "\n");
```

Comment: A que te refiere con seleccionar? me parece que solo es dar click al TextView no es así? @user126636

Comment: si es darle click al textView pero como en el textView muestra varios datos ocupo solamente como seleccionar una dato al darle click

Comment: muestro varios datos y los separo por una linea que puse en el código y queda en el textview como una lista entonces lo que ocupo hacer es seleccionar un  dato y que me aparescan dos botones pero no lo he conseguido

Comment: no me podras ayudar o dar un consejo de como hacerlo

Comment: @Elenasys cuando muestros los datos me queda como si fuera una lista y tengo que dar click algun dato de los que me muestra para despues hacer ciertas actividades con el dato seleccionado

Comment: si me explique ahora @Elenasys

Comment: Me imagino que no puedes seleccionar por el momento los elementos?, lo que sucede es que este tipo de elemento no tiene selección, solo puedes dar clic

Comment: asi es no puedo seleccionar la parte que quiero y ando un poco confundido de como hacerlo no se si me podras ayudar

Comment: solo quiero seleccionar de uno por uno no todo junto si me explico y pues ahi esta el codigo que puse en el while

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93312/discussion-on-question-by-user126636-como-seleccionar-lo-que-tengo-en-un-textvie).

Comment: ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un listener, y al dar click cambiar la propiedad de visibilidad de los botones, por ejemplo

```
Tipo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

       boton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       boton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     }
});
```

Comment: pero eso no me seleccionaría todo? yo no quiero que me seleccione todo por ejemplo en cada vuelta que hace el while pone un parrafo con toda la informacion en otra vuelta que hace el while pone otro parrafo y asi se va dependiendo de cuanta informacion se traiga la base de datos y la muestra en un textView del cual solo quiero seleccionar un parrafo

Comment: es que creo que no me estoy explicando o si me entendiste?

Comment: que te pareces si tienesuna imagen

Comment: si si la tengo pero como la envio